# Update changes of a component when executing function from another one with angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

i have a student component which display a list of students on loading page. I've created another component to add a student, i would like when i click on submit automatically the student component will be changed and display the new student without refreshing the page. for this purpose, after adding a student, i call the function onGetStudents() from the service i show you the solution i've implemented below but it doesn't work!

```
@Injectable()
export class myservice {

  constructor(private  httpClient:HttpClient){}

    onGetStudents(){
       return this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/students");
    }
} 



export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit{

   constructor(private  httpClient:HttpClient,private myservice:myservice) { }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.getStudents();
       }

 getStudents(){
    this.myservice.onGetStudents()
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.listStudents=data;
      },err=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}



 export class addStudentComponent implements OnInit {
      student:any;
      constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient,private myservice:myservice) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      onSaveStudent(student){
        this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/students",students)
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.student=data;
            this.myservice.onGetStudents();
          },err=>{
            console.log(err);
          })
      }
    }
```

PS: i added the myservice in the providers of course.

Comment: create a service that holds the student. Then, let both of the components feed off the service.

Comment: Hi Michael, i updated my post like you said, it doesn't work. Maybe i've missed something !

Comment: We'd need to see what your myservice code looks like as well

Comment: It's already in the code above.

Comment: Let check the params of post API `students` or `student`

Comment: Hello, Thank you all, problem resolved, i was mistaken, i added the child component(add-student) in the app-component and this is faulse, so i have to add it in studentComponent, That's all.